# Automate averaging sets of columns in excel

Tags: excel, data-analysis

I have to average sets of 3 columns.

EXAMPLE:

`Blood_Patient1_0_R1`, `Blood_Patient1_0_R2`, `Blood_Patient1_0_R3`

There average is in a new column `Blood_Patient1_0`

Similarly, `Blood_Patient1_3_5_R1`, `Blood_Patient1_3_5_R2`, `Blood_Patient1_3_5_R3`

The average is in a new column `Blood_Patient1_3_5`

This process is being repeated for 8 such sets of columns.

Currently I am averaging using the formula: `IF(ISERROR(AVERAGE(B7:D7)),"",AVERAGE(B7:D7))` and auto-filling 21,000 plus rows.

Since there is a pattern in column headings, I was thinking to automate the whole process.

This is what I have thought so far in terms of algorithm:

- 0, 3_5, 6_25 are time values in column headers.
- at each time instant, there are 3 replicates R1, R2,R3 as part of column headers

> for `time` array [3.5h, 6.25h, 9.5h, 11.5h, 16.5h, 25h, 49h, and 156h
>   ]
>
> create a new column
>
> for rows from 2 to 21458
>
> average over `replicates` from R1 to R3 using above formula

I do not know how to write this in excel. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is it that you're looking to automate? Do you have to regularly import new data to the spreadsheet and then add the average columns? if so I would just recommend formatting a range as a table with one row, the last column of which contains the average formula. When you paste in your data it will apply the formula automatically to the entire dataset.

Comment: @MJV.... i wish to write a script that looks for Blood_Patient1_T_RX column. and for each time T = [3_5, 6_25, 9_5, 11_5, 16_5, 25, 49, and 156]  it averages RX = [R1, R2, R3] column for each row (total rows = 21456).

Answer (score 0):

Give this a go.

This solution assumes that you have a continuous data set, that is, no gaps between the columns you wish to search through.

Firstly, you will need to include this function. Paste it into the same module as the subroutine. The purpose of this function is to allow the string in each heading to be compared against an array of substrings, as opposed to the single substring permitted by the `InStr` function.

```
Function Time_Search(strCheck As String, ParamArray anyOf()) As Boolean

Dim item As Long

For item = 0 To UBound(anyOf)

    If InStr(1, strCheck, anyOf(item)) <> 0 Then

        Time_Search = True

        Exit Function

    End If

Next

End Function
```

Next, paste in this subroutine. I have assummed that the dataset begins at cell A1. Also, I have allowed for a dynamic range, should the number of columns or rows ever change.

```
Sub Insert_Average_Columns()

Dim HeaderRange As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim c As Range

Set HeaderRange = Range(Range("A1"), Range("A1").End(xlToRight))
LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For Each c In HeaderRange.Cells

If Right(c.Value, 2) = "R3" Then

    If Time_Search(c.Value, "3_5", "6_25", "9_5", "11_5", "16_5", "25", "49", "156") Then

        c.Offset(0, 1).EntireColumn.Insert
        c.Offset(0, 1) = "Average of " & Left(c.Value, Len(c.Value) - 3)
        c.Offset(1, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(AVERAGE(RC[-3]:RC[-1]),"""")"
        c.Offset(1, 1).AutoFill Range(c.Offset(1, 1).Address, Cells(LastRow, c.Offset(1, 1).Column))

    End If

End If

Next c

End Sub
```

There is one issue with your data. If you want the procedure to insert an average column for T = 25, then it will do so for all columns where T contains the string "25". If there are T= 8.25, 10.25, 15.25, etc, these will all have averages applied. The only way around it would be to include more of the heading string in the parameter array, but I presume you will be dealing with a variable Blood_Patient ID so that probably isn't an option.